# múltiplos de 2 e 3 em python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, while

Estou fazendo um código para calcular os primeiro(s) n(s) múltiplos de dois valores, e colocar em uma lista.
até ai perfeito mas na lista ocorre múltiplos números iguais, como poderia tirar os número iguais da lista?

```
n = int(input('Quantidade de múltiplos'))
i = int(input('Primeiro valor '))
j = int(input('Segundo valor '))
s = 0
lista = [0]
while s < n:
    s += 1
    m1 = i * s
    m2 = j * s
    lista += [m1, m2]
    lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para definir essa lista você não precisa fazer qualquer validação. Basta relembrar os conceitos de matemática básica, de que o primeiro múltiplo dos dois valores será o mínimo múltiplo comum (mmc, do inglês *least common multiple*) e os posteriores serão múltiplos desse valor. Ou seja, inicie a lista com o MMC e calcule os N-1 múltiplos desse valor:

```py
import math


n = int(input('Quantidade de múltiplos: '))
i = int(input('Primeiro valor '))
j = int(input('Segundo valor '))

lcm = math.lcm(i, j)
result = [lcm * x for x in range(1, n+1)]
```

Para `n=10`, `i=2` e `j=3` teríamos a saída:

```
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para calculares os múltiplos de dois valores podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
m = int(input('Digite o primeiro número: '))
n = int(input('Digite o segundo número: '))
q = int(input(f'Desejas calcular quantos múltiplo de {m} e de {n}? '))

soma1 = soma2 = 0
mult1 = list()
mult2 = list()
while len(mult1) < q and len(mult2) < q:
    soma1 += m
    soma2 += n
    mult1.append(soma1)
    mult2.append(soma2)

print(f'Os {q} primeiros múltiplos de {m} são: {mult1}')
print(f'Os {q} primeiros múltiplos de {n} são: {mult2}')
```

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite o primeiro número:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o primeiro valor e pressionar `enter`. Depois recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite o segundo número:` . Neste momento devemos digita o segundo número e pressionar `enter`. Depois recebemos a terceira mensagem: `Desejas calcular quantos múltiplos de {m} e {n}?` . Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade de múltiplos de ambos os números e pressionamos `enter`.

Depois disso o bloco `while` irá executar `q` iterações e, para cara iteração será adicionado a soma acumulada de seus valores nas listas `multi1` e `multi2` respectivamente e, posteriormente, exibirá abas as listas contendo seus respectivos múltiplos.

**Observação:**

Este código é capaz de calcular uma quantidade de múltiplos de quaisquer dois números. inteiros.

Answer (score 0):

Não tente fazer tudo numa só operação. Divida o seu código em pequenos passos:

- Colete os dado iniciais do usuário.
- Crie duas listas. Uma lista irá armazenar os múltiplos do primeiro número, a segunda lista irá armazenar os múltiplos do segundo número.
- Itere pelo intervalo **[1 , Quantidade de múltiplos + 1[** e vá apensando a cada uma das lista seus respectivos múltiplos.
- Junte as duas lista e remova os duplicados(passo posteriormente implementado na linguagem criando um [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) que é uma coleção não ordenada sem elementos duplicados).
- Ordene o resultado(posteriormente implementado na linguagem usando a função bulti-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted))

Exemplo:

```
n = int(input('Quantidade de múltiplos: '))
i = int(input('Primeiro número: '))
j = int(input('Segundo número: '))

#Declare l1 e l2 duas listas vazias.
l1, l2 = [], [] 

#Para c variando no intervalo [1, n + 1[
for c in range(1, n + 1):
  l1.append(c * i)   #Apense o c-ésimo múltiplo de i a lista l1.
  l2.append(c * j)   #Apense o c-ésimo múltiplo de j a lista l2.    

s1 = set( l1 + l2 )  #Remove os duplicados ao unir as listas l1 e l2.
print(sorted(s1))    #Imprime o resultado ordenado
```

Resultado:

```
Quantidade de múltiplos: 5
Primeiro número: 2
Segundo número: 3
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15]
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SuperStableDos)

Answer (score 0):

Se o que deseja são os n números que sejam **simultaneamente** múltiplos dos dois números tente:

```
n = int(input('Quantidade de múltiplos: '))
i = int(input('Primeiro valor '))
j = int(input('Segundo valor '))
s = 0
lista = []
while len(lista) < n:
     s += 1
     if (s % i == 0 and s % j == 0):
         lista.append(s)
print(lista)
```